# AnacondaでOSMnxを使用したい

Tags: python, anaconda

jupyterでの実装内容

```
import osmnx as ox
G = ox.graph_from_place('Manhattan Island, New York City, New York, USA', network_type='drive')
ox.plot_graph(ox.project_graph(G))
```

エラー内容

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-22e533a47a02> in <module>
----> 1 import osmnx as ox
      2 G = ox.graph_from_place('Manhattan Island, New York City, New York, USA', network_type='drive')
      3 ox.plot_graph(ox.project_graph(G))

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/osmnx/__init__.py in <module>
      1 """OSMnx init."""
      2 
----> 3 from ._api import *
      4 from ._version import __version__

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/osmnx/_api.py in <module>
      2 
      3 from .bearing import add_edge_bearings
----> 4 from .distance import get_nearest_edge
      5 from .distance import get_nearest_edges
      6 from .distance import get_nearest_node

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/osmnx/distance.py in <module>
      9 
     10 from . import utils
---> 11 from . import utils_geo
     12 from . import utils_graph
     13 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/osmnx/utils_geo.py in <module>
     12 from shapely.ops import split
     13 
---> 14 from . import projection
     15 from . import settings
     16 from . import utils

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/osmnx/projection.py in <module>
      3 import math
      4 
----> 5 import geopandas as gpd
      6 from pyproj import CRS
      7 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/geopandas/__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from geopandas._config import options  # noqa
      2 
      3 from geopandas.geoseries import GeoSeries  # noqa
      4 from geopandas.geodataframe import GeoDataFrame  # noqa
      5 from geopandas.array import points_from_xy  # noqa

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/geopandas/_config.py in <module>
    124 use_pygeos = Option(
    125     key="use_pygeos",
--> 126     default_value=_default_use_pygeos(),
    127     doc=(
    128         "Whether to use PyGEOS to speed up spatial operations. The default is True "

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/geopandas/_config.py in _default_use_pygeos()
    112     import geopandas._compat as compat
    113 
--> 114     return compat.USE_PYGEOS
    115 
    116 

AttributeError: module 'geopandas._compat' has no attribute 'USE_PYGEOS'
```

その他に不足している情報があれば指摘して頂きたいです。

Answer (score 0):

2021年8月8日現在、次の手順でANACONDAからosmnxが使えました。

1. ANACONDA.NAVIGATORで環境を作ります。
   　環境作成は必須ではありませんが、やり直しするとき環境をリムーブするだけでよいので、新しく環境を作成することをお勧めします。
2. ANACONDA.NAVIGATORからCMD.exe Promptを起動します。
   　CMD.exeがLaunchではなくInstallとなっている場合はインストールしてください。
3. CMD.exeでチャネルconda-forgeのosmnxをcondaでインストールします。

```
conda install -c conda-forge osmnx
```

https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/osmnx

---

- 質問された方の環境で発生しているエラーメッセージをみてもよくわかりませんでした。
  ためしに新たな環境を作成し、osmnxをインストールしたところエラーは発生せず、Manhattan Islandが図示されました。
- この問題が発生した原因はわかっていません。

  - osmnxまたはosmnxで直接または間接的に使用しているモジュールのバージョンにバグがあったのかもしれません。
  - モジュール間のバージョンに不整合があったのかもしれません。
  - モジュールのインストールがうまくいっていなかったのかもしれません。